# How to show a ViewGroup on click without changing the screen in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have two buttons on home screen A & B. On clicking either of them, respective forms should appear in the same screen. I am not able to show the forms without launching a new screen.

Comment: Fragments sound like what you are looking for  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using dialogs I used the Ids of the layouts set in the XML file and then changed the **setVisibility()** to *GONE* and *VISIBLE* on the call of respective action buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a dialog for this? The guid to this can be found at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html.

Comment: Dialog can't fulfil design requirements for the app